# Illegal Unit of Measure with \textwidth using VS Code Extension

Tags: textwidth, unit-of-measure

This causes the error:

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width= 0.4/textwidth]{Bilder/Hochsetzsteller.PNG}
\end{figure}
```

I'm using the following settings to compile:

```
[{
    "resource": xxx",
    "owner": "LaTeX",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).\n<to be read again> \n",
    "source": "LaTeX",
    "startLineNumber": 138,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 138,
    "endColumn": 65536
}]
```

The funny thing is that I use `scrreport` and on my titlepage I include a picture the same way and it doesn't create an error.

I have read many threads but i couldn`t find the issue of this Problem.

Comment: There is a typo: `0.4/textwidth` is not a valid length, but `0.4\textwidth` would be. You've used a slash instead of a backslash.

Comment: BTW: It is recommended to always show a minimal working example instead of a code snippet only. Working examples not only help us to reproduce the problem and to understand it. They also help in finding a solution and show an answer with complete code. See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that for more information.

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo in the shown code. It has to be

```
\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width= 0.4\textwidth]{Bilder/Hochsetzsteller.PNG}
\end{figure}
```

Note: In LaTeX lengths like commands always start with a backslash not a slash. So `/textwidth` is just text not a length. And so after `0.4` a valid unit is missing. The unit can either be a real unit like `pt`, `cm`, `em` etc. or a length like `\textwidth` (but not `/textwidth`).